# Why is the date time offset the same for eastern and central time?

Tags: c#, time, timezone, timezone-offset

I created a small app to test storing times with the UTC offset. I don't understand the results. If I run the program at 14:01 today, I get this:

This:

```
InsertPunch(new Employee { Id = 10, TimeZoneId = "Central Standard Time" });
```

Produces this in the DB:

> 2021-01-08 **13**:01:06.3594141 -05:00

This:

```
InsertPunch(new Employee { Id = 12, TimeZoneId = "Eastern Standard Time" });
```

Produces this in the DB:

> 2021-01-08 **14**:01:07.5587251 -05:00

The times are correct; the first is indeed CT and the second is indeed ET. But **why is the offset -5 for both**? Shouldn't the offset for CT be -6? I was assuming we could look at a time like this:

> 2021-01-08 14:01:07.5587251 -05:00

...and we know that UTC time is 19:01 (14:01 + 5:00). That's correct. But the results for CT are incorrect: 13:01 + 5:00 = 18:01, and the current UTC time is actually 19:01.

Am I understanding this incorrectly? Or perhaps I'm doing something wrong?

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        InsertPunch(new Employee { Id = 10, TimeZoneId = "Central Standard Time" });
        InsertPunch(new Employee { Id = 12, TimeZoneId = "Eastern Standard Time" });

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to end.");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void InsertPunch(Employee employee)
    {
        var punchTimeUtc = DateTime.UtcNow; // Need timestamp in UTC to properly convert to employee's time zone.

        var timeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(employee.TimeZoneId); // Reference the employee's time zone.
        
        var punchTimeInUsersZone = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(punchTimeUtc, timeZoneInfo);

        var punch = new Punch
        {
            EmployeeId = employee.Id,
            PunchTime = punchTimeInUsersZone
        };

        string sql = "INSERT INTO [time].[Punch] ([EmployeeId],[PunchTime]) VALUES (@EmployeeId, @PunchTime)";

        using (IDbConnection db = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            db.Execute(sql, new { punch.EmployeeId, punch.PunchTime });
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Larnu Why remove the SQL Server tag?

Comment: What about the question is related to SQL Server? (Note that saying that the code has a SQL Server back end doesn't make it related to SQL Server).

Comment: The results are from what ends up in SQL Server. I think that might be relevant if the data type of the column matters, SQL Server settings, etc.

Comment: You're storing UTC.  The offset you see is from whatever you're using to view it converting that to your time zone.

Comment: The problem is you're inserting the wrong data; that isn't SQL Server's fault. That the fault of the C# code. SQL Server doesn't change the data (unless there's a trigger you're not telling us about).

Comment: @juharr When a time is stored like that, is it UTC time and -5 gets you to the local time zone, or is it stored as local and +5 gets you to UTC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe what is occurring is that the field in your database is a `datetimeoffset` type (as evidenced by the offset appearing in the examples you pasted), but you are passing .NET `DateTime` values into the parameter as you insert data into that field.

In such a case, the SQL client will silently coerce those values using the same effects as described with .NET's `DateTime` to `DateTimeOffset` implicit conversion operator.  From [those docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.op_implicit):

> ... The offset of the resulting `DateTimeOffset` object depends on the value of the `DateTime.Kind` property of the `dateTime` parameter:
>
> - If the value of the `DateTime.Kind` property is `DateTimeKind.Utc`, the date and time of the `DateTimeOffset` object is set equal to `dateTime`, and its `Offset` property is set equal to 0.
> - If the value of the `DateTime.Kind` property is `DateTimeKind.Local` or `DateTimeKind.Unspecified`, the date and time of the `DateTimeOffset` object is set equal to `dateTime`, and its `Offset` property is set equal to the offset of the local system's current time zone.

In the code you gave, `punchTimeInUsersZone.Kind` will always be `DateTimeKind.Unspecified` and thus will use the system local time zone when deciding which offset to apply.  Thus you store -5 because you are in the Eastern time zone and the date falls into the standard time period.

The resolution is to use .NET `DateTimeOffset` types in your code instead of `DateTime`.

- First, change the `PunchTime` property on your `Punch` class to `DateTimeOffset`.
- Then change the conversion logic in your `InsertPunch` method as follows:

  ```
  DateTimeOffset punchTimeUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
  TimeZoneInfo timeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(employee.TimeZoneId);
  DateTimeOffset punchTimeInUsersZone = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(punchTimeUtc, timeZoneInfo);
  ```

The rest is fine as is.

Comment: That did it. I already had the `PunchTime` property as `DateTimeOffset`, so I just needed your last line of code to call `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime` instead of `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc`. Thank you.

Comment: That makes sense.  But still make sure you're using `DateTimeOffset` throughout.  It will avoid any other possible occurrences of this issue, and will prevent having to deal with ambiguous time edge cases during DST fall-back transitions.